# Doubt in finding critical point by partial differentiation.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

For a given $G=X_{a}G_{a}+X_{b}G_{b}+\Omega X_{a}X_{b}+RT(X_{a} lnX_{a}+X_{b}ln X_{b} ) $;$X_{a}=1-X_{b}$,I am having trouble with finding the second order derivative$\partial ^2G/\partial x_{b}^2$.Somebody told me,"the first two term disappear because the are linear. The second term is $x-x^2$ and the 2nd derivative is $-2$ and the last term is basically $x \log x + (1-x) \log(x-1)$ and the 2nd derivative is ${1 \over x} + { 1\over x-1}$".However the final value that I get is given by the picture(this is after taking the first derivative).$T_{Cr}=2\Omega x(1-x)/R.$Now the value of x is set to 0.5 for getting the critical value of the function that I found in terms of T. Firstly,how do I calculate x=0.5 which gets me the critical value of temperature.Also how do I judge whether the critical value is maximum or minimum?Last but not the least these are all partial derivatives,how is the differentiation technique going to be different than from a normal derivative?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Typeset in MathJax instead.

Comment: @K.defaoite Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding (since I am the 'somebody') is that we are looking at the expression
$G(x) = G_a (1-x)+ G_b x + \Omega x(1-x) + RT(x \ln x + (1-x) \ln (1-x))$.

If you differentiate $x \mapsto G_a (1-x)$ twice you get zero.

If you differentiate $x \mapsto G_b x$ twice you get zero.

If you differentiate $x \mapsto x(1-x)$ twice you get $-2$.

If you differentiate $x \mapsto x \ln x + (1-x) \ln (1-x) $ twice you get
${1 \over x}+{1 \over 1-x}$.

Hence
$G''(x) = -2 \Omega + RT ({1 \over x}+{1 \over 1-x} ) = -2 \Omega + RT {1 \over x(1-x)} $.

I have no idea what the $x=0.5$ part of the question means, but it is straightforward to check (assuming $x \in (0,1)$) that $x={1 \over2}$ minimises the function $x \mapsto -2 \Omega + RT {1 \over x(1-x)} $.

I am not exactly sure what the last part of the questions means, but the calculus of differentiation is the same for differentiation & partial differentiation.

If You differentiate one more time and set to zero you get
$G'''(x) = RT {(2x-1) \over x^2 (1-x)^2} = 0$ and we see that $x={1 \over 2}$ is the only solution.

Comment: But how do you get $x=0.5$?That is my question.Rest seems fine.

Comment: If you minimise the function over $x$ on the interval $(0,1)$ then the minimiser occurs at $x={1 \over 2}$. You can get this by diffferentiating and equating to zero.I have no idea what the interpretation is.

Comment: How do I do this minimization.Please tell the steps.

Comment: @user586228 The usual calculus way, differentiate and equate to zero (as I said in my last comment). I have added the last step.

Comment: Why should I differentiate one more time..What does three time differentiation indicate..

Comment: Generally a first approach to finding an unconstrained extreme point of $f$ is to look at $f'(x) = 0$. Here $f(x) = G''(x)$. I have no idea what the physical interpretation of $G$ is, so I cannot comment on that. I have no idea what you are doing, I can only assume some thermodynamics thing, I am just computing the derivatives and making observations.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for.Thanks a lot :)